# modx creating new lexicon entry event

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I need to create a plugin in modx revolution. I need to set plugin event when some one will create or update a lexicon entry from modx lexicon management.I want to save created/updated lexicon entry to somewhere else. I have been searching in googles and see modx documentations. I could not find useful links. Any ideas or links will be helpful.

Thanks,
Awlad

Comment: Take a look at new feauture (introduced in 2.2) called [class-based processor](https://www.markhamstra.com/xpdo/2012/getting-started-with-class-based-processors-2.2/) but i am not sure if you can extend Lexicon related classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use plugins: http://rtfm.modx.com/evolution/1.0/developers-guide/plugins and you would be wanting to look into system events: http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/basic-development/plugins/system-events
What I would suggest is to use OnDocFormSave for your plugin, then you should be able to read lexicon data as it is has already loaded the lexicon it needs with these functions: http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/advanced-development/internationalization
I really hope this helps, but feel free to ask again and I will try my best to help. :)